# Error de Microsoft VBScript en tiempo de ejecución: No coinciden los tipos

Tags: oracle, vba, script

Estoy haciendo un script que ejecuta sentencias para luego insertarlas en un reporte en Excel el problema es que en una parte del código me da el siguiente error:

> Error de Microsoft VBScript en tiempo de ejecución: No coinciden los
>   tipos.

Lo que estoy ejecutando es lo siguiente:

```
  if (RecordData.fields("DB_NAME").value < RecordRedos.fields("DB_NAME").value) or _
     ((RecordData.fields("DB_NAME").value = RecordRedos.fields("DB_NAME").value) and (RecordData.fields("FIRST_CHANGE#").value < RecordRedos.fields("FIRST_CHANGE#").value)) then
     rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
     rem -- Insertamos DB DATA 
     rem -------------------------------------------------------------------

     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyType     )=Cstr("Database")
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDBName   )=Cstr(get_db_name(RecordData.fields("DB_NAME").value))
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDBID     )=Cstr(get_dbid(RecordData.fields("DB_NAME").value))
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyIncarn   )=Cstr(get_Incarnation(RecordData.fields("DB_NAME").value))
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudySCNFrom  )=Cstr(RecordData.fields("FIRST_CHANGE#").value)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudySCNTo    )=Cstr(RecordData.fields("LAST_CHANGE#").value)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDateFrom )=Cstr(RecordData.fields("FIRST_TIME").value)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDateTo   )=Cstr(RecordData.fields("LAST_TIME").value)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudySize     )=RecordData.fields("BYTES").value / 1024 / 1024
     row = row + 1
     recordData.MoveNext
  else
     rem -------------------------------------------------------------------
     rem -- Insertamos REDO
     rem -------------------------------------------------------------------

     memredos(0) = RecordRedos.fields("DB_NAME").value
     memredos(1) = RecordRedos.fields("FIRST_CHANGE#").value
     memredos(2) = RecordRedos.fields("NEXT_CHANGE#").value
     memredos(3) = RecordRedos.fields("FIRST_TIME").value
     memredos(4) = RecordRedos.fields("NEXT_TIME").value
     memredos(5) = RecordRedos.fields("BYTES").value

     dummy = fetchRedos(RecordRedos)

     memredos(2) = dummy(0)
     memredos(4) = dummy(1)
     memredos(5) = dummy(2)

     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyType     )="Redos"
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDBName   )=get_db_name(memredos(0))
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDBID     )=get_dbid(memredos(0))
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyIncarn   )=get_Incarnation(memredos(0))
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudySCNFrom  )=memredos(1)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudySCNTo    )=memredos(2)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDateFrom )=memredos(3)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudyDateTo   )=memredos(4)
     sheet.cells(row, fldStudySize     )=memredos(5) / 1024 / 1024
     row = row + 1

  end if

  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudyDBID     ).NumberFormat = fmtNumInteger 
  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudySCNFrom  ).NumberFormat = fmtNumInteger 
  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudySCNTo    ).NumberFormat = fmtNumInteger
  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudyIncarn   ).NumberFormat = fmtNumDate
  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudyDateFrom ).NumberFormat = fmtNumDate
  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudyDateTo   ).NumberFormat = fmtNumDate
  sheet.cells(row-1,fldStudySize     ).NumberFormat = fmtNumDecimal


  if row mod 500 = 0 then traza "Estudio backup: " & CStr(row) & " registros."
wend
```

He intentado castear algunos valores pensado que ese era el problema pero me ha seguido apareciendo el mismo error.

Comment: Y seguiste el codigo para ver que linea tira el error?

Comment: Adjunto la línea del error: C:\DBA\makeinforme_2.txt(430, 7) Error de Microsoft VBScript en tiempo de ejecución: No coinciden los tipos, según esto el error salta al comienzo del if